# Convert Flutter Android/iOS project into a package so it can be downloaded in another flutter projects

Tags: flutter, plugins, package

I have created a Flutter application which can run on iOS and android.
I want to convert it into a package which can be installed in other flutter apps.

my Flutter app is a basic framework app with integrated push notification feature using azure notification hub, TDD, remote logging, azure service bus connection, use of graphQL and sending event to EventGrid in Azure. etc....

I want this framework to be downloaded as a plugin with single command in another flutter projects. is it possible?

My expectations is to download the entire project as a package/plugin into another flutter project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

---

1. Create a new Flutter package:

```bash
flutter create --template=package .
```

2. Move your code into the lib directory.
3. Create a sample app (optional).
4. Publishing the package in [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/) (public)

```bash
# pub authentication
flutter pub login
# or
dart pub login

# Publish your package
# --dry-run flag checks for potential issues before publishing
pub publish --dry-run
pub publish
```

5. Use the package in other projects.

```yaml
dependencies:
  # hosted in pub.dev
  my_public_package: ^1.0.0
```

If you want to make it private you can either include the package within the project, or use private repository such as Github or Bitbucket, then point the package directory to repository url in `pubspec.yml`

```yaml
dependencies:
  # hosted in github/bitbucket
  my_private_package:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/your-username/my_private_package.git

  # included within the project
  my_local_package:
    path: /path/to/your/local/repo/my_local_package
```

Note: you probably need to modify your existing code, and export its functionalities as it's required to be a package. [Flutter docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will try this and update. About  ' export its functionalities' you mean like authentication as a functionality should be separate package, notification as a separate package?

Comment: I meant by `export` is to make it accessible by external resources either different package or applications. You can check [flutter doc](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/create-packages). In addition, it would be appreciated to accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: This worked fine. Thank you so much. I am using my Artifacts of Azure devOps to publish my package. (Universal Package) and downloading from there to use it. So that worked fine.